# My Arduino Code but it will not compile, I cannot find what is wrong with it

Tags: arduino-mega

I tried convining and LCD display, ultrasonic sensons, LEDs and an IR reciever code into one main code. Seperately they work fine, but when I put them toguether it gives me the following error: "Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560."

The full error when I compile is :

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_13'
libraries/IRremote/IRremote.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YNOqxE0mAZJsQrV7_zMbRZ_jkur19rXt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: have you tried adding two at a time, rather than all or one approach - perhaps then *you* can determine which two don't co-exist (if all 6 conbinations of two at a time always works, then try 3 at a time) - at least, that's how I'd approach the issue if the error messages did not indicate the nature of the problem

Comment: You must post your code and you must also use proper formatting or your question will get closed very quickly

Comment: I attached the Code to the post

Comment: Your code should be pasted into the question, a link to the code might expire. If it is too long to include then it should be reduced down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The processor has a fixed number of hardware devices such as timers and serial ports. If two libraries try to use the same device (in this case it looks like timer 2) then you won't be able to compile (let alone run) the code without resolving the issue. Possibly one of them could be altered to use a different timer, however this may not be trivial.

As an example, say you have one alarm clock, but you want to have it ring at both 5 a.m. and 7 a.m. You can't do that per se, you might need to get a second clock.

---

Looking at the source code in `(install directory)/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avriomxx0_1.h` I see that vector 13 is indeed for Timer 2;

```
/* Timer/Counter2 Compare Match A */
#define TIMER2_COMPA_vect_num   13
#define TIMER2_COMPA_vect       _VECTOR(13)
#define SIG_OUTPUT_COMPARE2A        _VECTOR(13)
```

Comment: It is Timer2 interrupt with tone() and IRremote, same as here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=120955.0

Comment: Judging by the datasheet `_vector_13` is "Pin Change Interrupt Request 2" so it might be something to do with pin change interrupts. I didn't look at the code as it wasn't posted above.

Comment: When I use the library manager and install IRremote by shirriff and add a tone() call and compile it for the mega 2560, then I get a __vector_13 error. I don't know how vector number 13 is related to Timer2, but it is.

Comment: Thanks Jot, i was able to figure out what to do.

Comment: @Jot you are right - I looked it up in the source.